# Connecting to CODA debug agent from Qt Creator over WLAN

Tags: qt-creator, symbian, remote-debugging

I installed CODA on my Nokia 5800, and set it to use WLAN instead of USB.

It's running now, saying:

```
Welcome to CODA for Symbian OS

Status: Connected

WLAN Address: 192.168.2.113
WLAN Port number: 65029
```

But what do I do from the Qt Creator side? Qt Creator is still saying `No device is connected. Connect a device and try again.`. I'm assuming that I have to input the IP/port somewhere in Qt Creator settings, so it knows where to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it, from `Projects->Targets->Run`, set the `Communication Channel` to `WLAN`, and then type the IP address and port.

[image]